# How to log out from Stack Exchange

Tags: support, login

I get signed in automatically, I don't like this.
Also I do not see any option to logout or signout

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How do I log out of this site?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/10911/150988)

Answer (score 7):

To log out:

[image]

which takes you here:

[image]

If you want to not be remembered across browser settings, you'll need to set your browser to clear cookies from `*.stackexchange.com` on exit; there is no easy way to do this on-site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you can avoid being signed in automatically. An authentication token is set when you first log in and you will be logged in automatically until the token expires. Presumably, you can delete this (perhaps by clearing your cookies) but I don't really know how.

Logging out, however, is easy:

[image: open menu with log out link highlighted]

Just click on the Stack Exchange menu in the top bar, and then click on "log out".